# Abstract Indent

Tags: indentation

How can i indent my abstract? I've tried this:

```
\begin{abstract}
\indent
My abstract is this.
\end{abstract}
```

But it's not working. I'm even using `\usepackage{indentfirst}` that seems to work in indenting every other first paragraph of my text.

Edit: I've tried using the command:

```
\setlength{\absparindent}{0pt}
```

Inside the abstract environment, with different values, 1pt, 2pt... but nothing seems to change.

Edit 2: Added a MWE, hope this helps someone to figure this out.

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    oneside,                % para impressão apenas em verso.
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel.
    chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    section=TITLE,      % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    subsection=title,   % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras minúsculas
    subsubsection=title,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras minúsculas
    brazil              % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    ]{abntex2}

\usepackage{indentfirst} % Para identar o primeiro paragrafo
\begin{document}

\begin{agradecimentos}

 Thanking notes! As you can see, the "identfirst" package works here.

\end{agradecimentos}


\begin{resumo}[Resumo]

This is my abstract, help please. The "identfirst" package doesn't work here.

\vspace{\onelineskip}

\textbf{Palavras-chave}: abstract, help.

\end{resumo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Are you able to provide us with a minimal example that replicates your current setup?

Comment: Using abntex2. Yeah, just posted a mwe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The abstract is defined by the class to be without indentation. Something one just finds by looking at the `.cls` file. I just copied and modified it to be just like average, normal paragraphs.

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    oneside,                % para impressão apenas em verso.
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel.
    chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    section=TITLE,      % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    subsection=title,   % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras minúsculas
    subsubsection=title,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras minúsculas
    brazil              % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    ]{abntex2}

% A norma não diz nada sobre identação e separação entre parágrafos no abstract,
% porém o uso mostra que muitos abstracts são montados sem identação.
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \setlength{\absparindent}{\parindent}
}


\begin{document}

teste

teste para mostrar que não precisa de indentfirst

teste


\begin{resumo}[Resumo]


This is my abstract, help please. The "identfirst" package doesn't work here. This is my abstract, help please. The "identfirst" package doesn't work here. 


This is my abstract, help please. The "identfirst" package doesn't work here. This is my abstract, help please. The "identfirst" package doesn't work here.

This is my abstract, help please. The "identfirst" package doesn't work here.


\vspace{\onelineskip}

\textbf{Palavras-chave}: abstract, help.

\end{resumo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. But now it's also indenting the key-words. This is pissing me off to be honest, it's just some people in the library of my university demanding stuff that i know it doesn't exist in the thecnical norm.

Comment: @MuriloAraujoSouza `\noindent\textbf{Palavras-chave}...`

Comment: Great, it's fixed. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

`\indent` does not work as the code LaTeX inserts to remove the indentation after a section heading really does remove the indentation box, even if added explicitly.

Try

```
\section{hhh}
\hspace*{\parindent}aa bb ccaa
```

See the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{What are the fundamental gaps in scientific knowledge?}
\author{Robin Wilson}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\hspace*{\parindent}aa bb ccaa Recent reports by the global environmental ...
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Here is the text of your introduction.

And another paragraph here.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need all the packages in your example code?

Comment: the packages are not all required--built in for another MWE--copy and paste job--packages can be removed as per requirement

Comment: The standard `article` class *does* indent the first paragraph in the abstract; with this code you get *twice* the normal indent.

Comment: Thanks. But i'm sorry, this is not working for me. The identation here is too small.

Answer (score 0):

More simple and clean way is insert `\phantom{2em}` in front of abstract. And, you can specify the space your want.